# Possible dynamic allocation issues

Tags: c++, exception, memory-management, segmentation-fault, new-operator

Right now i'm trying to get my code(simple POD containers) running as stable as humanly possible. My main concern is memory allocation and deallocation(new[] and delete[] operators). Is it possible to get any undesired behavior out of them(like SIGSEGV or exceptions)?
Here's a little test example i wrote:

```
class my_vector{
    private:
        long* _data;
        size_t _size;
        size_t _capacity;
    public:
        my_vector()
       {
           this->_data = new long[10];
           this->_size = 0;
           this->_capacity = 10;
       };

        ~my_vector()
       {
           delete[] this->_data;
       };

        void add(long value)
       {
           if (this->_size == this->_capacity)
                 this->expand();
           this->_data[this->_size] = value;
           this->_size++;
       };
    private:
        void expand()
        {
           long* tmp = new long[this->_capacity*2];
           memcpy(tmp, this->_data, sizeof(long)*this->_size);
           this->_capacity *= 2;
           delete[] this->_data;
           this->_data = tmp;
        };
}
```

Comment: Please read or review  [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If you check that the alocations are succesfull, and dont delete data that is not yours, you should have no problems. When you allocate here: `this->_data = new long[10];` you dont check if the allocation was succesfull. And, if you copy any object from this class, you will get in some serious problems. I would recomend you to: 1. Check if the allocations where succesfull and 2. Follow the [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). If you do both, you should have no problems at all. Take a look into smart pointers, that might help

Comment: @Pablochaches  - `this->_data = new long [10]` will throw an exception if it fails.   That doesn't need to be checked (although the exception will eventually need to be caught, otherwise the program will terminate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `new[]` expression, by default, throws an exception if it fails (e.g. if a dynamic memory allocation fails).

If the constructor of any of the objects being constructed fails by throwing an exception, then the `new []` expression will have the (net) effect of throwing that exception.    Some other things also happen before the exception is finally emitted - for example, if construction of the third object in a dynamically allocated array fails,  the destructors for the two previously constructed objects will be called.   As far as calling code is concerned, if an exception is emitted, then none of the objects created by the `new[]` expression have ever existed.   This is specified in the standard.

If an exception is thrown and never caught, the program will terminate.   That is normal and expected.

A `delete []` expression will generally not throw unless a destructor of an object being destroyed throws.   Defining a destructor which throws is usually considered very poor practice, so should be avoided.

There is a `nothrow` form of a `new` expression, that does not - in itself - throw exceptions.   In that case, the `new` expression gives a null pointer on failure.

`new[]` and `delete []` expressions do not, in themselves, cause `SIGSEGV`, or any other form of abnormal termination.  If that occurs, it is a sign that some *other* code has exhibited undefined behaviour (e.g. written past the end of an array).   That can be in the constructor or destructor of the objects in the array, or in other code.